# Getting [InvalidFormatException] while trying to read docx file

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, docx

Packages used:
Apache poi 3.11
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11
poi-ooxml-3.11
xmlbeans 2.6.0

I am trying to read a docx file and converting it into text. This is the code

```
XWPFDocument wd;
        try {
            wd = new XWPFDocument(is);
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            XWPFWordExtractor wde = new XWPFWordExtractor(wd);
            bodyText=wde.getText();
            System.out.println(bodyText);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is the error message

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:122)
at project.fileupload.TagParsing.fileParseForTags(TagParsing.java:33)
at project.fileupload.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:105)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:203)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:673)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:274)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    ... 22 more

I have done a lot of searching to find the solution but to no avail. I am absolutely sure that the file is docx and it opens just well in Word. Help appreciated.

Comment: docx file is basically a zip file with a structure of files... so you should rename it to .zip and explore the contents in order to see what is relevant to you

Comment: What do you mean by exploring the contents? How do you do that in the servlet

Comment: Well, I would do it manually first. I would see what information I need and where it is located and then I'd see what can I do code-wise

Comment: text can usually be found in yourFile.docx.zip/word/document.xml

Comment: Where did the file come from? And if you load it in word and save it again, does the problem go away?